# Rotating/moving objects

Tags: c#

I have a situation that I am not quite sure where to start looking. I have been searching for the past four hours and I couldn't find anything that does what I am looking to do.

I have eight objects controlling individual lights. When an event occurs I generate an ID of it, store that value in the first available object, and start a method. I also store the ID in a list and match the object number to the index number of that list. What I would like to do is have those eight objects update and rotate depending if the matching item is removed from the list.

Example: There are five out of the eight objects active and I remove an item from the list indexed at 0. Object 0 is stopped then object 1 is moved to object 0 then 2 to 1, 3 to 2, etc.

So my question is what terms should I look up to help me accomplish that goal? I am relatively new to c# and with the results of my research today I just want to know what is the right question to ask.

If what I am looking to do is impossible just say so and I will come up with a more simple program on my end. Or if you have a solution to that situation I am all ears.

Comment: What are you storing the objects in? If you use a `List<T>` you can remove the first object, and the second one will now be the first.

Comment: Is there a language that you're more familiar with?

Comment: `Queue<T>` is available in .NET Framework, priority queue is not but there is quite few implementations.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by rotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just describing a [stack data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type).  Check it out and see if it's what you're looking for.

A stack doesn't "rotate" objects, but when you remove the top item, the "index" of all the other items will decrement as you described.  In your example, it seems like the list would eventually become empty (after 8 events) which is consistent with a stack - but it's not clear why one would call this rotation.

If a stack is what you're looking for, the BCL defines a generic [`Stack<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) that can do this.  You add items to a stack with the `Push()` operation, which has the side effect of incrementing the index of all other items in the structure.  The dual `Pop` operation removes the top item from the collection and decrements the index of the other items, as you described.

Comment: This looks promising. I will start playing around with this tomorrow.

Comment: @TehSolarbear - just added some more explanation that clarifies a few points - definitely make sure you saw the most recent edit

Comment: My main issue with this question is terminology. I am not sure what words to use while describing what I want to do.

Comment: Could you pop an object at a different point in the stack or does it always have to come from the top of the stack?

Comment: @TehSolarbear - The default .NET implementation only lets you `Pop` from the top.  But, you can access any of the items in the stack by enumerating, e.g. `foreach(var item in stack)` - The difference is this does not change any state.  The stack will be the same before and after you iterate over it.  The `System.Linq` namespace gives you an extension method [`ElementAt(int index)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb299233(v=vs.100).aspx) that can be used to select items at an arbitrary index, but this is based on enumeration and consequently will not change any state either.

Comment: @TehSolarbear - If it's hard to find the words to say what you mean, but you're idea is clear in your mind, then try drawing a picture or a series of pictures that represent the changes to the thing you want to build.